# Java code to capture each keyword in square bracket?

Tags: java, regex, split

I am getting output of java code within brackets, i need to retrieve each keyword
    inside a bracket?

Output Shows :

```
[Eiwitten, 4,8, g]
```

from this I need to retrieve each keyword  like:

```
Eiwitten
4,8
g
```

So please help me, how to resolve in java coding?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `\[(.+)\]` and then `split`?

Answer (score 0):

The way suggested by Maroun Maroun is simple and efficient, you can use it but with this pattern: `\\[([^]]+)]`

If you want to do it with a single pattern:

```
(?:\\G(?!\\A)|\\[(?=[^]]*]))(.+?)(?:, |(?=]))
```

if you know that square brackets are balanced, you can make shorter with:

```
(?:\\G(?!\\A)|\\[)(.+?)(?:, |(?=]))
```

Note: These two patterns don't allow empty items.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 String str ="[Eiwitten, 4,8, g]";
        str = str.replaceAll("\\[", "");
        str = str.replaceAll("\\]", "");
        String[] split = str.split(", ");
        for(int r = 0 ; r <split.length ; r++){
            System.out.println(split[r]);
        }
```

Comment: I got solution : Eiwitten 4,8 g. Thanks Miya.

Answer (score 0):

you could also use this pattern to capture text between `", "`

```
, |([^\]\[]+?)(?=, |\])
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/142)

```
,               # ", "
|               # OR
(               # Capturing Group (1)
  [^\]\[]       # Character not in [^\]\[]
  +?            # (one or more)(lazy)
)               # End of Capturing Group (1)
(?=             # Look-Ahead
  ,             # ", "
  |             # OR
  \]            # "]"
)               # End of Look-Ahead
```